# How can I alter this shadow effect to make this text more readable?

Tags: css

I am currently working on a project where I have text over a gradient background. I am using the shadow CSS property but I can't seem to get the desired effect. I want this to be more readable, perhaps more like a stroke effect. Is this possible? Check below to see how the numbers ".90" and ".87" blend in too much with the background. Here is my simple CSS :

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000000;
```

If I blur more, the numbers are even harder to read. What can I do? My shadow color is already solid black, so I am out of ideas but I am hoping there is a CSS property that may help this be more readable.

[image]

Comment: You can repeat the shadow a few times to increase its effect . Repeat  each shadow with a coma , in between. text-stroke is on its way ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from my earlier comment :

> You can repeat the shadow a few times to increase its effect . Repeat each shadow with a coma , in between. text-stroke is on its way ...

[`text-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow) :

> The text-shadow CSS property adds shadows to text. It accepts a comma-separated list of shadows to be applied to the text and any of its decorations. Each shadow is described by some combination of X and Y offsets from the element, blur radius, and color.
>
> This property is specified as a comma-separated list of shadows.
>
> Each shadow is specified as two or three `<length>` values, followed optionally by a `<color>` value. The first two `<length>` values are the `<offset-x>` and `<offset-y>` values. The third, optional, `<length>` value is the `<blur-radius>`. The`<color>` value is the shadow's color.
>
> When more than one shadow is given, shadows are applied front-to-back, with the first-specified shadow on top.

```css
body {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000000, 1px 1px 2px #000000, 1px 1px 2px #000000;
}


/* demo purpose*/

body {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #d22f09cc, #ebc906cc, #fffc, #b2c207cc, #70c2cdcc);
  text-align: justify-content;
  text-align-last: justify;
  margin-top:30vh;
  
}

html {
  background: url(https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.LD3HdvuKE4oi4s2K4fQbKQHaHa?pid=Api&rs=1) 0 0 / 35vh 35vh repeat-x;
}

body:before,
body:after {
  content: "0";
  color: #fff0;
  text-shadow: 0 0
}
```

```html
12 34 56 78 90 12 34 56 78 90
```

[`-webkit-text-stroke`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke) **Non-standard** , probably not efficient with small font-size.

> The `-webkit-text-stroke` CSS property specifies the `width` and `color` of strokes for text characters. This is a shorthand property for the longhand properties `-webkit-text-stroke-width` and `-webkit-text-stroke-color`.

```css
body {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000000;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #555;
}


/* demo purpose*/

body {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #d22f09cc, #ebc906cc,#fffc, #b2c207cc, #70c2cdcc);
  text-align: justify-content;
  text-align-last: justify;
  margin-top: 30vh;
}

html {
  background: url(https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.LD3HdvuKE4oi4s2K4fQbKQHaHa?pid=Api&rs=1) 0 0 / 35vh 35vh repeat-x;
}

body:before,
body:after {
  content: "0";
  color: #fff0;
  text-shadow: 0 0;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0 #0000;
}
```

```html
12 34 56 78 90 12 34 56 78 90
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add multiple shadows to increase the depth of it:

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px grey, 0 0 1px grey, 0 0 0.2px grey;
```

When more than one shadow is given, shadows are applied front-to-back, with the first-specified shadow on top.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow)

Answer (score 1):

Because of my poor eyesight (cylinders in both eyes creating 'ghost letters'), I use the following code to make dark text on a bright background stand out a bit more (make it a tiny bit bolder and crispier), mimicking MS Windows 'cleartype':

```
[cleartype="1"] { text-shadow: .1px  .1px .2px hsla(0,0%,15%,.35),
                              -.1px -.1px .2px hsla(0,0%,15%,.25) }
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,b,strong,
[cleartype="0"] { text-shadow: none } /* exceptions, no need to go even 'bolder' */
```

Used as `<body cleartype="1">` it makes normal text stand out more, making it easier (for me) to read. It is a very subtle effect, some thick fontfaces won't even show any difference and only works with dark text on a bright background.

I adjusted the above code to work for light text on a dark (or rainbow coloured) background. In the final result, even white text on a white background is (fairly) readable.

Use it to your advantage.

Commented **snippet** with a few examples...

```css
[class^="rainbow"] {
    position: relative; /* create new 'stacking context' */
    display: flex; justify-content: space-around; /* Flexbox Layout */
    width: 100%;

    line-height: 1.75; /* determines the rainbow height, centers text vertically */
}

[class^="rainbow"]>* {
    z-index: 1; /* on top of background (the ::after) */

    color: White; font-size: 1em; font-weight: bold;

    /*           x-offset    y-offset    blur       color           */
    text-shadow:  0.031250em  0.031250em 0.015625em hsla(0,0%,10%,.35),
                 -0.015625em -0.015625em 0.187500em hsla(0,0%,10%,.25),
                 -0.006250em -0.006250em 0.187500em hsla(0,0%,10%,.15);
    /* for px values: multiply by 16. Here in em to scale proportionally with fontsize */
    /* fiddle with hsla ligthness and alpha values to get desired effect */

    /* could actually degrade shadow effect, try it with/without => text appears brighter without. */
/*    -webkit-text-stroke: 0.25px hsla(0,0%,10%,.25); /* keep px value very low for subtle effect */
}
[class^="rainbow"]::after {
    position: absolute; /* within current 'stacking context' (which is .rainbow) */
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; content: '';

}

.rainbow-1 {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    /* Official names (not the HTML names) */
    /* red, orange, yellow, chartreuse, green, aquamarine, cyan, azure, blue, violet, magenta, rose */                            

    background-image: linear-gradient(to right,
                                      rgba(255,  0,  0,.8),
                                      rgba(255,127,  0,.8),
                                      rgba(255,255,  0,.8),
                                      rgba(127,255,  0,.8),
                                      rgba(  0,255,  0,.8),
                                      rgba(  0,255,127,.8),
                                      rgba(  0,255,255,.8),
                                      rgba(  0,127,255,.8),
                                      rgba(  0,  0,255,.8),
                                      rgba(127,  0,255,.8),
                                      rgba(255,  0,255,.8),
                                      rgba(255,  0,127,.8)
                                     );
    /* modify current alpha value (.8) to get required transparency, make 1 for fully opaque */
}

/********/
/* DEMO */
/********/
.rainbow-2   { background-color: White } /* to test without background-image */
.rainbow-3   { background-color: Grey }
.rainbow-3>* { color: Silver }
.rainbow-4   { background-color: Black }
.rainbow-4>* { color: LightYellow }

/*
    'y = mx + b'  math reference: https://www.mathsisfun.com/equation_of_line.html
*/
/* responsive base fontsize using y = mx + b */
html { font-size: calc(0.625vmin + 0.75rem) } /* (320,14)(1280,20) */
body { font-size: 1rem }

.wrapper {
    display: flex; flex-flow: column wrap; align-content: center;

/*
    padding using y = mx + b

    Top/Bottom padding: p1(320,16) p2(1920, 72) => 0.035x + 4.8  => vary from 16 to  72px
    Left/Right padding: p3(320, 8) p4(1920,320) => 0.195x - 54.4 => vary from  8 to 320px
*/
    padding: calc(3.5vh + 4.8px) calc(19.5vw - 54.4px);

    background-color: rgba(164,22,54,1); /* picked from OP original image */
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
    <div class="rainbow-1">
        <div> .10</div>
        <div> .20</div>
        <div> .30</div>
        <div> .40</div>
        <div> .50</div>
        <div> .60</div>
        <div> .70</div>
        <div> .80</div>
        <div> .90</div>
        <div>1.00</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rainbow-2">
        <div> .10</div>
        <div> .20</div>
        <div> .30</div>
        <div> .40</div>
        <div> .50</div>
        <div> .60</div>
        <div> .70</div>
        <div> .80</div>
        <div> .90</div>
        <div>1.00</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rainbow-3">
        <div> .10</div>
        <div> .20</div>
        <div> .30</div>
        <div> .40</div>
        <div> .50</div>
        <div> .60</div>
        <div> .70</div>
        <div> .80</div>
        <div> .90</div>
        <div>1.00</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rainbow-4">
        <div> .10</div>
        <div> .20</div>
        <div> .30</div>
        <div> .40</div>
        <div> .50</div>
        <div> .60</div>
        <div> .70</div>
        <div> .80</div>
        <div> .90</div>
        <div>1.00</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Bonus**

Code showing how to use *linear equations* to create responsive sizing without using *@media queries*, [the Math](https://www.mathsisfun.com/equation_of_line.html).